# Wcf service saving changes to database using entity framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, wcf

I am trying to update/add data using wcf service and entity framework. I have 2 implementation of the same function. The first one is working perfectly. Here is the code for the first one:

```
        public bool SaveEmployee(Employee employeeEntity)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SaveEmployee has been executed");
        using (var context = new iposEntities())
        {
            context.Database.Log = Console.Write; 
            using (var trans = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    if (employeeEntity.EmployeeID == 0)
                    {

                        context.employees.Add(new employee()
                        {
                           //EmployeeID=employeeEntity.EmployeeID,
                           NationalIDNo= employeeEntity.NationalIDNo,
                           FullNames= employeeEntity.FullNames,
                           Title = employeeEntity.Title.ToString(),
                           TitleOfCourtesy=employeeEntity.TitleOfCourtesy,
                           BirthDate=employeeEntity.BirthDate,
                           HireDate=employeeEntity.HireDate,
                           Address=employeeEntity.Address,
                           City=employeeEntity.City,
                           Phone=employeeEntity.Phone,
                           ReportsTo=employeeEntity.ReportsTo,
                           Salary=employeeEntity.Salary,
                           Password = employeeEntity.Password,
                           Status =  Convert.ToSByte(employeeEntity.Status)

                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        employee EmpEntity = context.employees.First(i => i.EmployeeID == employeeEntity.EmployeeID);

                        EmpEntity.NationalIDNo = employeeEntity.NationalIDNo;
                        EmpEntity.FullNames = employeeEntity.FullNames;
                        EmpEntity.Title = employeeEntity.Title.ToString();
                        EmpEntity.TitleOfCourtesy = employeeEntity.TitleOfCourtesy;
                        EmpEntity.BirthDate = employeeEntity.BirthDate;
                        EmpEntity.HireDate = employeeEntity.HireDate;
                        EmpEntity.Address = employeeEntity.Address;
                        EmpEntity.City = employeeEntity.City;
                        EmpEntity.Phone = employeeEntity.Phone;
                        EmpEntity.ReportsTo = employeeEntity.ReportsTo;
                        EmpEntity.Salary = employeeEntity.Salary;
                        EmpEntity.Password = employeeEntity.Password;
                        EmpEntity.Status = Convert.ToSByte(employeeEntity.Status);
                        context.Entry(EmpEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;

                    }

                    context.SaveChangesAsync();

                    trans.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    trans.Rollback();
                    Console.WriteLine("An error occured during saving"+ex.Message);
                }
            }


        }
            return true;

    }
```

The second implementation (which is not working) is here:

```
 public bool SaveEmployee(Employee employeeEntity)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SaveEmployee has been executed");
        using (var context = new iposEntities())
        {
            context.Database.Log = Console.Write; 
            using (var trans = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    if (employeeEntity.EmployeeID == 0)
                    {

                        context.employees.Add(employeeEntity);

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        context.Entry(employeeEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;

                    }

                    context.SaveChangesAsync();

                    trans.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    trans.Rollback();
                    Console.WriteLine("An error occured during saving"+ex.Message);
                }
            }


        }
            return true;

    }
```

Here is a error message from Visual studio: Error   10  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'iPos.Interfaces.Employee' to 'iPos.Service.employee'   C:\Dropbox\UniversalApp\iPos\iPos.Service\PosService.cs 241 51  iPos.Service

Please help what am i doing wrong? I believe my Employee POCO Class is Ok. Here is my POCO Class

```
 public class Employee : IEditableObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    EmployeeData backupEmplData;
    private int employeeID;
    private string nationalIDNo;
    private string fullNames;
    private OccupationPositions title;
    private string titleOfCourtesy;
    private Nullable<System.DateTime> birthDate;
    private Nullable<System.DateTime> hireDate;
    private string address;
    private string city;
    private string phone;
    private Nullable<int> reportsTo;
    private Nullable<float> salary;
    private string password;
    private bool status;
    private string photo;

    public struct EmployeeData
    {
        internal int employeeID;
        internal string nationalIDNo;
        internal string fullNames;
        internal OccupationPositions title;
        internal string titleOfCourtesy;
        internal Nullable<System.DateTime> birthDate;
        internal Nullable<System.DateTime> hireDate;
        internal string address;
        internal string city;
        internal string phone;
        internal Nullable<int> reportsTo;
        internal Nullable<float> salary;
        internal string password;
        internal bool status;
    }
    public Employee()
    {

    }
    public enum OccupationPositions
    {
        GeneralEmployee,
        CEO,
        Casheer,
        Accountant,
        Foreperson,
        InventoryOfficer,
        StockManager,
        supervisor,
        Security,
        SuppliesManager,
        StaffManager,
        HygeneStaff,
        SalesRepresentative,
        HR,
        MarketingOfficer,
        FinancialOfficer,
        Receptionist,
        MarketingManager,
        PurchasingManager,
        Consultant,
    }
    public Employee(int employeeID, string nationalIDNo, string fullNames, OccupationPositions title, string titleOfCourtesy, Nullable<System.DateTime> birthDate, Nullable<System.DateTime> hireDate, string address, string city, string phone, Nullable<int> reportsTo, Nullable<float> salary, string password, bool status)
    {
        this.backupEmplData = new EmployeeData();

        backupEmplData.employeeID = employeeID;
        EmployeeID = employeeID;
        backupEmplData.nationalIDNo = nationalIDNo;
        NationalIDNo = nationalIDNo;
        backupEmplData.fullNames = fullNames;
        FullNames = fullNames;
        backupEmplData.title = title;
        Title = title;
        backupEmplData.titleOfCourtesy = titleOfCourtesy;
        TitleOfCourtesy = titleOfCourtesy;
        backupEmplData.birthDate = birthDate;
        BirthDate = birthDate;
        backupEmplData.hireDate = hireDate;
        HireDate = hireDate;
        backupEmplData.address = address;
        Address = address;
        backupEmplData.city = city;
        City = city;
        backupEmplData.phone = phone;
        Phone = phone;
        backupEmplData.reportsTo = reportsTo;
        ReportsTo = reportsTo;
        backupEmplData.password = password;
        Password = password;
        backupEmplData.status = status;
        Status = status;

    }
    public void BeginEdit()
    {
        this.backupEmplData.employeeID = EmployeeID;
        this.backupEmplData.nationalIDNo = NationalIDNo;
        this.backupEmplData.fullNames = FullNames;
        this.backupEmplData.title = Title;
        this.backupEmplData.titleOfCourtesy = TitleOfCourtesy;
        this.backupEmplData.birthDate = BirthDate;
        this.backupEmplData.hireDate = HireDate;
        this.backupEmplData.address = Address;
        this.backupEmplData.city = City;
        this.backupEmplData.phone = Phone;
        this.backupEmplData.reportsTo = ReportsTo;
        this.backupEmplData.salary = Salary;
        this.backupEmplData.password = Password;
        this.backupEmplData.status = Status;
    }

    public void CancelEdit()
    {
       EmployeeID=this.backupEmplData.employeeID;
       NationalIDNo= this.backupEmplData.nationalIDNo;
       FullNames= this.backupEmplData.fullNames;
       Title= this.backupEmplData.title;
       TitleOfCourtesy=this.backupEmplData.titleOfCourtesy;
       BirthDate=this.backupEmplData.birthDate;
       HireDate=this.backupEmplData.hireDate;
       Address=this.backupEmplData.address;
       City=this.backupEmplData.city;
       Phone=this.backupEmplData.phone;
       ReportsTo=this.backupEmplData.reportsTo;
       Salary=this.backupEmplData.salary;
       Password = this.backupEmplData.password;
       Status = this.backupEmplData.status;


    }

    public void EndEdit()
    {
        this.backupEmplData.employeeID = EmployeeID;
       this.backupEmplData.nationalIDNo=NationalIDNo;
       this.backupEmplData.fullNames=FullNames;
       this.backupEmplData.title=Title;
       this.backupEmplData.titleOfCourtesy=TitleOfCourtesy;
       this.backupEmplData.birthDate=BirthDate;
       this.backupEmplData.hireDate=HireDate;
       this.backupEmplData.address=Address;
       this.backupEmplData.city=City;
       this.backupEmplData.phone=Phone;
       this.backupEmplData.reportsTo=ReportsTo;
       this.backupEmplData.salary=Salary;
       this.backupEmplData.password=Password;
       this.backupEmplData.status = Status;
    }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [Display(AutoGenerateField=false)]
    public int EmployeeID
    {
        get
        {
            return employeeID;
        }
        set
        {
            employeeID = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("EmployeeID");
        }
    }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [Required]
    public string NationalIDNo {
        get
        {
            return nationalIDNo;
        }
        set
        {
            nationalIDNo = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("NationalIDNo");
        }
    }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [Required]
    public string FullNames {
        get
        {
            return fullNames;
        }
        set
        {
            fullNames = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("FullNames");
        }
   }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [Required]

    [Display(Name = "Position")]
    public OccupationPositions Title
    {
        get
        {
            return title;
        }
        set
        {
            title = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Title");
        }
   }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]

    public string TitleOfCourtesy {
        get
        {
            return titleOfCourtesy;
        }
        set
        {
            titleOfCourtesy = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TitleOfCourtesy");
        }
   }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [Required]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> BirthDate {
        get
        {
            return birthDate;
        }
        set
        {
            birthDate = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("BirthDate");
        }
    }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [Required]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> HireDate {
        get
        {
            return hireDate;
        }
        set
        {
            hireDate = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("HireDate");
        }
   }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]

    public string Address {
        get
        {
            return address;
        }
        set
        {
            address = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Address");
        }
   }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]

    public string City { 
        get
        {
            return city;
        }
        set
        {
            city = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("City");
        }
    }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [Required]
    public string Phone {
        get
        {
            return phone;
        }
        set
        {
            phone = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Phone");
        }
    }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]

    [Display(Name="On Contract")]
    public bool Status
    {
        get
        {
            return status;
        }
        set
        {
            status = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Status");
        }
    }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [Display(AutoGenerateField = false)]
    public Nullable<int> ReportsTo {
        get
        {
            return reportsTo;
        }
        set
        {
            reportsTo = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ReportsTo");
        }
    }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]

    public Nullable<float> Salary {
        get
        {
            return salary;
        }
        set
        {
            salary = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Salary");
        }
    }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [Required]

    public string Password {
        get
        {
            return password;
        }
        set
        {
            password = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Password");
        }
    }
     [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]

     [Display(AutoGenerateField = false)]
    public string Photo
    {
        get
        {
            return photo;
        }
        set
        {
            photo = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Photo");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have 2 versions of Employee:
one in 'iPos.Interfaces.Employee'
another in 'iPos.Service.employee'

Even if they use the same source code, for the compiler they are 2 different classes.
Just use only one.